# MessageAndMetadata cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, message

The current import that I used for MessageAndMetadata cannot be resolved
this is the import that I have used import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata; which cannot be resolved to a type.
I want to implement this in kafka 2.8

Comment: Can you add some details about your application and some sample code or dependencies configuration?

Comment: I am trying to create a Function f1
Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, String>, Object> function1 = new Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, String>, Object>

the kafka version I want to use is 2.8.1.7.2.15.0-147
the old import that i used is import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata which I think is deprecated.
so i am looking for an alternative import that have MessageAndMetadata in it.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1.7.2.15.0-147</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was deprecated in version 2.0 (it doesn't appear in version 2.0 https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/message/MessageAndMetadata.scala, but it is still present in the previous 1.1 version https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/message/MessageAndMetadata.scala)

Given that you want a version compatible with broker 2.8 and that Kafka guarantees that newer library versions can connect to old broker version, but not the other way around, I don't think you will be able to find a version that has the `MessageAndMetadata` class and that is compatible with 2.8.